# Can a span within an H1 harm bot attempts to identify the text?

Tags: seo, html, googlebot, markup

I am wondering if this structure can confuse search bots and prevent them from identifying the contents of the H1.

For example, in the code below, can the bot identify "Main Text" as the H1 content?

```
<h1 itemprop="name">Main 
<span class="lastword-title">Text
  <span class="verify-biz glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="certified company">    
  </span>
</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: You should be fine, however, my best advice is not to confuse important HTML elements. Cheers!!

Comment: Although 5+ years old now, the linked question should be sufficient:  if it wasn't a problem back then, it certainly isn't now that bots have gotten even better at parsing content.